# How to let the user set a username during registration with Django social-auth?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I use Django social-auth (omab version just to avoid any confusion with the other similarly named project) and right now I am trying it with Facebook. It is possible to register a new user and to login/logout without any issue. The only thing that I would like to add is a form during registration to let the user enter the desired username to be used on site because at the moment the username is either a facebook username (I do not want to force the user to use the same username) or a uuid if there is no facebook username (and that is ugly).

I am reading the docs, the pipelines and all that stuff but I'm not sure to understand, any hint or explanation would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it in the example app that comes with social-auth https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example/app. There is an example of the pipeline to use and even the form and views you need to implement. Very few to no changes are necessary to have a working implementation. At least some work needs to be done on the form at the time I write this because you can enter a username already taken.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer links to an entire GitHub project without explaining anything about what parts of it are relevant, and some of it is outdated, so I'll try to share what I've learned.

django-social-auth is deprecated and the replacement is [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django), which integrates Django with the [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core) project.

The documentation on python-social-auth [Pipelines](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html) is relevant. In the default pipeline, this is the stage that generates the username:

```
# Make up a username for this person, appends a random string at the end if
# there's any collision.
'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
```

The [implementation of `get_username`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/pipeline/user.py#L9) shows the default behavior. We will have to copy these aspects:

- It ensures that the username it comes up with is unique, by checking `storage.user.user_exists(username=...)` and modifying the username until it is unique.
- It returns the dictionary `{'username': '...'}`, which is passed to the next stages in the pipeline.

To prompt the user, we need a custom ["partial" pipeline stage](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#partial-pipeline). This lets us pause the pipeline to wait for the user to submit the username form and then resume it once we have the username.